# how to pass an array and other fields in ajax and laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

I am uploading multiple files using ajax and laravel. I storing files names in MySQL database. In the controller, I am checking whether I am getting an array or not. Only else block is working. When I submit data it is not passing an array. I don't know why. Please check my code where I am wrong.

Thank you

```
 <form  enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">

      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
       Select Event
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
             <select name="eventname"  class="form-control">
                 <option disabled selected>Select</option>
                 @foreach($event as $eve)
                 <option value="{{$eve->id}}">{{$eve->title}}</option>
                 @endforeach
             </select>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">

        <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
         Upload A file
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
               <input type="file" id="eventgallery" class="form-control" name="eventgallery[]" multiple>
        </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div id="images">

        </div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

ajax code

```
$('#eventgallery').on('change',function(){
    var image = '';
    $.ajax({
      url : '{!! url('uploadimage') !!}',
      date: new FormData(this.form),
      method:'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      success:function(data)
      {
          console.log(data);
      }

    });

});
```

controller

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->file('eventgallery');

        if (is_array($name) || is_object($name))
        {
            foreach($name as $file)
            {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $filename = asset('uploads/eventgallery'.$request->eventname.rand(11111,9991).'.'.$extension);
                $file->move("uploads/eventgallery",$filename);

                $event = EventGallery::create([
                    'event_name' => $request->eventname,
                    'eventimage_url' => $filename
                ]);
            }
            $eve = Event::find($request->eventname);
            $eventgallery = $eve->galleryies;
            return response()->json($eventgallery);
        }
        else
        {
            return response()->json('it is not a array');

        }



   }
```

Comment: What error you are getting in console?

Comment: if I remove If condition it is showing invalid argument supplied to foreach or it is not an array else block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are sending the post variables as `date`. It should be `data`.

```
$('#eventgallery').on('change',function(){
    var image = '';
    $.ajax({
      url : '{!! url('uploadimage') !!}',
      data: new FormData(this.form),
      method:'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType:false,
      cache:false,
      processData:false,
      success:function(data)
      {
          console.log(data);
      }

    });

});
```

Comment: thank you very much. A silly mistake and trying from last 2 hours.why it was not showing any error?

Comment: I tried the same code. You should check the console for errors. It showed me 500 error code with line number in console.